# .net alternative to Start-Process

Tags: powershell, start-process

I am using powershell to manage a benchmark of Autodesk's Revit product. It uses `Start-Process -wait` to run Revit with a journal file as an argument, and the journal file allows for consistently repeating the same test. The issue I am seeing is that often either the Revit startup is very slow, compared to a "manual" startup, or there is a VERY long (sometimes a minute or more) pause between Revit closing and Powershell continuing. Since I sometimes repeat this process with as many as 20 journals, it leads to a very long test process.

What I wonder is, is there a more performant replacement for Start-Process. Often in Powershell there is a less performant but very syntactically convenient native Powershell cmdlet, and there is a much more performant but syntactically fussy .NET version. Is this true for Start-Process too?

Or is there perhaps some addressable issue related to how quickly Powershell responds after control is returned?

Comment: I would start by writing a short script that contains only the minimum amount of code needed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you do want to go down the .NET route, I'd take a look at [Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=netcore-3.1) and [ProcessStartInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo?view=netcore-3.1), however, please note, that I'm reasonably sure that Start-Process just uses these classes in it's source code.

Comment: I'll make some time tomorrow to build a minimal script that uses `Start-Process`, and `Process`, and wrap them both in a timer to see what happens. Well, if I can figure out how to get it to work. Translating .NET documentation to a PowerShell implementation is still hit or miss for me. ;-)

Comment: Unless you've hit a bug in `Start-Process`, using the underlying .NET types directly cannot be expected to make a noticeable difference - if it does, the potential `Start-Process` bug is worth reporting.